# What does "extra" field mean in composer.json file?

Tags: php, json, composer-php

I try to add `composer.json` file to my library. In many examples that I saw I found `"extra"` field, that look like:

```
"extra": {
    "branch-alias": {
        "dev-master": "2.0.x-dev"
    }
}
```

My question is:

Is this a required field?
What does it mean and what I must write in it?

Comment: https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#extra

Comment: Thanks, but it a very bit info about it and even without example :(

Comment: But thats what you asked for imo, I really tested it, and as written any arbitrary data can be put there. I put "aaa"->"bbb" and it worked. The onlyone other answer here does not answer the extra field, but other subfields although it is an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's aliasing the master branch. Composer uses GIT versions and branches to get the version number of a release. So a `1.2` branch can be used as `1.2@dev`, and a `v1.2.1` tag is the `1.2.1` version.

However, the `master` branch is vague for Composer. It can't parse a version from that name. The same applies to other branches that doesn't follow a common version name. You can refer to the master branch using `dev-master`, but that's not always considered to be a good practise.

Also, assume the `master` branch was the 2.0.x dev branch. If you want to install the master branch, you actually want the latest `2.0.x` dev version. So instead of referencing to a branch name (`dev-master`), you want to use something more semantic (`2.0.x@dev`). As a result, Composer can perfectly handle this when an alpha, beta, RC, etc. release is done for the latest `2.0.x` branch.

In order to make Composer doing this, you have to alias the branch (in this case the `master` branch) to a version. That's done in the `branch-alias` part of the `extra` section. In the code you provided, the `master` branch is set to be the dev version of the latest `2.0.x` release. So people can use `2.0.*@dev` in their `composer.json` and they will get this master branch installed.

**Short answer**: It's branch aliasing, for more information see ["Aliases"](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/aliases.md) of the documentation.

Comment: Thanks for complex answer!

Comment: Maerlyn replied this in the comment above, you give example of a subfield, and described that